# Is `free(a_comparable_pointer)` well defined or UB?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Certainly allocating and freeing the same pointer is well defined ...

```
void *p1 = malloc(42);
assert(p1);
...
free(p1);
```

... and converting though `intptr_t/uintptr_t` creates a *comparable* pointer (as in "compare equal" C11 7.20.1.4) when these integer types exist, although not necessarily the same bit pattern.  One could say `p2` and `p3` have the same *value*, but may have differing representations.

```
void *p2 = malloc(42);
assert(p2);
uintptr_t u2 = (uintptr_t) p2;
...
void *p3 = (void *) u2;

// Specified to evaluate true C11 7.20.1.4
if (p2 == p3) ...

// Maybe true, maybe false
if (memcmp(&p2, &p3, sizeof p2) == 0) ...

// Note - early version of post had this errant code
// if (memset(&p2, &p3, sizeof p2) == 0) ...
```

Now to `free()` via a *comparable* pointer.

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, ... if the argument does not **match** a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function ... behavior is undefined. C11dr §7.22.3.3 3

```
void *p4 = malloc(42);
assert(p4);
uintptr_t u4 = (uintptr_t) p4;
...
void *p5 = (void *) u4;
...
free(p5);  // UB or not UB?
```

So the title question appears to come done to:
Is "comparable" sufficient to "match" concerning `free()`?

I suspect `free(p5)` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B) (UB), but am not certain.  No particular application in mind - just trying to understand the corners of C, no rush.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparable"? Where did you get that term?

Comment: @user2357112  I derived "comparable from "compare equal" in C11 7.20.1.4 "... integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will **compare equal** to the original pointer:"

Comment: The word you're looking for there is "equal", not "comparable".

Comment: @user3386109 Right you are!  Post amended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References are to [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the latest publicly available draft of the 2011 ISO C standard (C11).

```
void *p4 = malloc(42);
assert(p4);
uintptr_t u4 = (uintptr_t) p4;
...
void *p5 = (void *) u4;
...
free(p5);  // UB or not UB?
```

The definition of `uintptr_t` guarantees that the pointer values `p4` and `p5` compare equal; more tersely, `p4 == p5`. From the definition of `==` for pointers in 6.5.9p6, we know that `p4` and `p5` point to the same object (since we've already established that the value of `p3` is not a null pointer).

This doesn't guarantee that they have the same representation. The standard says very little about the representation of pointers (except that they have a representation), so it's entirely possible that `p4` and `p5` have different representations.  The standard explicitly permits this in 6.2.6.1p4:

> Two values (other than NaNs) with the same object representation
>   compare equal, but values that compare equal may have different object
>   representations.

(That may or may not actually be possible, depending on the implementation.)

Now the question is, what exactly is passed to `free`?

Function calls are described in 6.5.2.2.  Paragraph 4 says:

> In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated,
>   and each parameter is assigned the **value** of the corresponding
>   argument.

(Emphasis added.)

So what `free()` sees is not the object representation of `p5` (which might differ from the object representation of `p4`), but the **value** of `p5`, which is guaranteed to be the same as the value of `p4`.  It's likely that the mechanism by which that value is passed might involve making a copy of the object representation, but all the standard says is that the value is passed, and `free` must treat any distinct representations of the same value in the same way.

Comment: Does the fact that pointers compare equal imply interchangeability?  I was under the impression that given something like `int foo,bar,*p1=1+&foo,*p2=bar;` the comparison `p1==p2` would not invoke UB but might arbitrarily yield true or false; even if the comparison yields true, however, `p1[-1]` and `p2[0]` would be well-defined, while `p1[0]` and `p2[-1]` would both invoke UB.  I think something stronger should be said about the result of conversions between `void*` and other types than that they merely compare equal.

Answer (score 3):

The type uintptr_t guarantees that a void pointer after the conversion to this type and back, will compare equal to the original pointer<sup>1</sup>.

If a pointer compares equal to another pointer, then they point to the same object<sup>2</sup>.

The behavior in the last example is thus defined and you can use that pointer to free the object: `free(p5)`

---

<sup>1</sup>   (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.20.1.4 Integer type capable of holding pointers 1)
The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
uintptr_t

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.9 Equality operators 6)
Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the
same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function,
both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer
to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different
array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address
space. 109)

Comment: Yes, two pointers that compare equal point to the same object.  Yet the question is if `free()` because of the "match" specification requires something more.

Comment: @chux The argument does match the pointer returned by a memory function. Match is just a word, you're over-analyzing it.

Comment: @chux If you look for other examples of using the word 'match' in the standard you will notice it is used as a synonym for 'compare equal'.

Comment: Would anything in the Standard forbid a compiler from changing a pointer to an object into a "just-past" pointer for a preceding object (making direct use  of indirection operators UB) when performing a cast, given that such a "just past" pointer would compare equal to the original?  I know interpreting the rules in such fashion would make the language pretty useless, but does anything in the Standard as written actually forbid it?

Comment: @supercat Not sure. I suggest you ask a question with an example if possible. Let me know if you do.

Comment: @2501: While I'm curious what holes in the spec have been addressed, I think trying to plug all the holes in the spec is counter-productive.  What I'd like to see is not for holes in the spec to be addressed by the Committee, nor exploited by compiler writers, but rather for compiler writers to recognize that the spec's failure to forbid something should not be taken as an indication that the authors intended that any implementations would do it.  The authors of the spec saw no need to mandate that compilers behave certain ways in cases where they couldn't imagine them doing otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The language about converting to and from `uintptr_t` uses "compare equal", but note that conversion between `void*` and `T*` uses the same phrase:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

(section 6.3.2.3/1 from the ISO C99 standard)

If *match* and *compare equal* were not synonyms, then by your reasoning the following would also be UB:

```
T* p = malloc(n);
...
free(p);
```

and instead would require:

```
void* p0 = malloc(n);
T* p = p0;
...
free(p0);
```

Which goes against common sense.  Furthermore, examples of `malloc` usage in the standard and in K&R 2nd edition do not do anything of the sort.

Comment: There are many situations where common sense suggest that quality implementations for a particular platform should regard behavior as defined in some particular case, but where "modern" implementations have seen fit to do otherwise.  I think the language about "compare equal" was written at a time when p==q implied that any operations that were defined on p would be defined identically on q.  The Standard later described situations where that principle no longer applies, but hasn't replaced the phrase "compare equal" with any stronger definition of equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

`free` doesn't know/care where the return value was store, or what type it later gets converted to (it gets converted back to a `void*`). Therefore, it doesn't matter what pointer you pass in as long as it points to memory that has been allocated and has not been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any call to free will be fine as long as it points to a valid heap block. The free behavior becomes unpredictable when the argument doesn't point exactly to the beginning of a valid heap block. For example, the code below will compile, but will crash during execution because the modified pointer doesn't point to a valid heap block:

```
int* pn = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
pn += 2;                // Now points beyond the beginning of an allocated heap block
void* pv = (void*)pn;   
free(pv);               // Therefore will crash
```

If you remove the pn += 2,  it will be fine again.
The bottom line: it is OK to modify and cast your pointers, but when you free them, you should make sure they point to saomething that was actually allocated and was not  already deallocated.